# Building business intelligence tool -- where to start?

Tags: probability, references, games, business-intelligence

I'm currently a web developer with a backgound mainly in server side technologies however I've always had an interest in probability so recently I've been exploring building a dummy betting platform where people wager against insurance policies and essentially I'm aiming to use data from Google's index to set the odds -- essentially like the Webbot but not for finance.

I know this is a massive endeavor so I don't expect to do it all but any suggestions on where to start are greatly appreciated. At the moment I'm brushing up on game theory, statistics, and some business intelligence tools however I wanted to know if anyone could recommend books or other resources which might be good starting points.

Also any suggestions about business intelligence tools also are greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question is extremely vague and difficult / impossible to answer in the current form. Can you hone in on a specific question that you need help on?

Comment: This is still quite a broad question -- as @Chase pointed out it would be better if you could define some specific problems you want to learn. It could be also a good idea to browse through [books tag](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books).

Comment: Thanks very much. The books tag really helped a lot because it shows a decent overview of the different areas in the realm. I'm just familiar with a few general terms so it was difficult for me to really pinpoint this question.